# Crystal report is not showing data on print, while it's showing data correctly on report viewer

Tags: c#, .net, crystal-reports

I'am having some weird behavior on crystal report. It's showing data correctly on report viewer. But when I try to print or export the same report its printing blank report (only parameters values are showing). I've spent hours trying to solve this problem but had no luck. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Code:

```
                        string fr = "{tblRegistration.id} = " + sID;
                        string img = Application.StartupPath + @"\Report\" + query.rptName + ".rpt";
                        ReportDocument cryRpt = new ReportDocument();
                        TableLogOnInfos crtableLogoninfos = new TableLogOnInfos();
                        TableLogOnInfo crtableLogoninfo = new TableLogOnInfo();
                        ConnectionInfo crConnectionInfo = new ConnectionInfo();
                        Tables CrTables;
                        cryRpt.Load(img);
                        crConnectionInfo.ServerName = Program.serverName;
                        crConnectionInfo.DatabaseName = Program.dbName;
                        crConnectionInfo.UserID = Program.saName;
                        crConnectionInfo.Password = Program.pw;
                        CrTables = cryRpt.Database.Tables;
                        foreach (CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.Table CrTable in CrTables)
                        {
                            crtableLogoninfo = CrTable.LogOnInfo;
                            crtableLogoninfo.ConnectionInfo = crConnectionInfo;
                            CrTable.ApplyLogOnInfo(crtableLogoninfo);
                        }

                        cryRpt.SetParameterValue("date", DateTime.Now.Date);
                        cr.SelectionFormula = fr;
                        if (!print)
                            cr.ReportSource = cryRpt;
                        else
                            cryRpt.PrintToPrinter(1, true, 1, 1);
```

Report Viewer Preview:

[image]

Report Print / Export:

[image]

Comment: Your code for exporting/printing and for previewing is probably not the same. Compare both codes and check if you fill up dataset with data before print/export of report.

Comment: what is the cr object? Probably it is what @KuKeC says, the first print is the result of cryRpt object's method and the second one of the other's. Show us more code, especially the functions that execute the different printings and how you call them